# I can't figure out why do I have a data-race

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am solving the dining philosophers problem to learn threads in C.

From what I understood about data races, I just have to lock a mutex, change it's value, then unlock.
Looks like this method works for the most part of my code, I see no data-races elsewhere with fsanitize.

But I only have 1 data race in my code and in a particular scenario :
-When I tell the thrads when to stop, when the time has come to stop, so when the threads has to check a value and change it to make the simulation stop, the datarace comes.
With the dining philosophers problem, it is when I tell how many meals they have to eat, and they reach this number of meals, they have to stop.

Here is where exactly the data race occurs. When I change the flag value to i.

```
int check_death(t_philo *philo, int i)
{
    int flag_value;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->sarg->mtx_flag);
    if (i != 0)
    {
        // DATARACE HERE
        philo->sarg->flag = i;
    }
    flag_value = philo->sarg->flag;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->sarg->mtx_flag);
    if (flag_value != 0)
    {
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

And here is the single thread representing a single philosopher.
The data race occurs when I call `check`*`death(philo, 2)`*
It is because multiple theads `phithread` are accessing checkdeath to change the `flag` value to 2.
But I don't understand how is that possible because I do lock the `mtx_flag` mutex.

```
void    *phithread(void *data)
{
    t_philo *philo;

    philo = (t_philo *)data;
    if (philo->id % 2 == 0)
        ft_usleep(philo->sarg->time2eat / 10);
    while (!check_death(philo, 0))
    {
        routine(philo);
        if (++philo->meals_eaten == philo->sarg->meals_to_eat)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->sarg->mtx_finish);
            philo->finish = 1;
            philo->sarg->satiated_philos++;
            if (philo->sarg->satiated_philos == philo->sarg->nb_philo)
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->sarg->mtx_finish);
                check_death(philo, 2);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&philo->sarg->mtx_finish);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&philo->sarg->mtx_finish);
            return (0);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I have tried to change the flag directly in the phithread function instead of using `check_death`, and locking the mutex before and unlocking after as usual but I had the same data race, nothing has changed.

Thanks to anyone helping !